# numpy broadcasting to all dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array build like this:

```
a = np.ones((3,3,3))
```

And I would like to broadcast values on all dimensions starting from a certain point with given coordinates, but the number of dimensions may vary.

For example if i'm given the coordinates `(1,1,1)` I can do these 3 functions:

```
a[1,1,:] = 0
a[1,:,1] = 0
a[:,1,1] = 0
```

And the result will be my desired output which is:

```
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Or if i'm given the coordinates `(0,1,0)` the corresponding broadcast will be:

```
a[0,1,:] = 0
a[0,:,0] = 0
a[:,1,0] = 0
```

Is there any way to do this in a single action instead of 3? I'm asking because the actual arrays i'm working with have even more dimensions which makes the code seem long and redundant. Also if the number of dimensions change I would have to rewrite the code.

EDIT: It doesn't have to be a single action, I just need to do it in all dimensions programatically such that if the number of dimensions change the code will stay the same.

EDIT 2: About the logic of this, i'm not sure if that's relevant, but i'm being given the value of a point (by coordinates) on a map and based on that I know the values of the entire row, column and height on the same map (that's why i'm updating all 3 with `0` as an example). In other cases the map is 2-dimensions and I still know the same thing about the row and column, but can't figure out a function that works for a varied numbers of dimensions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: *broadcast values on all dimensions at the same time starting from a certain point with given coordinates*? what do you mean by same time? there's no same time in python. If you mean one function please mention so. Also whats the exact logic behind your output?

Comment: Like I said in my edit at the end of the question - It doesn't need to be a single action or happen at the same time, but I want to at least loop across the dimensions like i'm doing manually line by line with my 3 broadcast actions. There are 3 actions because the array has 3 dimensions. If it had 2 dimensions I would only need 2 lines. But if the number of dimensions varies what do I do then?

Comment: @Kasramvd also I've added the logic behind this as an edit to the question

Comment: It seems that you want to find the combinations of the items in coordinate with length 2 and use them for indexing (slicing), is that right?

Comment: @Kasramvd yes i've selected an answer that uses slicing like that, I still wonder if you have any ideas for something better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method builds the slices with `np.repeat` and `np.fill_diagonal`.

```
a = np.ones((3,3,3))
target = (0, 1, 0)
slices = np.repeat([target], a.ndim, axis=0).astype(object)
np.fill_diagonal(slices, slice(None))

# slices
# array([[slice(None, None, None), 1, 0],
#       [0, slice(None, None, None), 0],
#       [0, 1, slice(None, None, None)]], dtype=object)

for t in slices:
    a[tuple(t)] = 0

array([[[0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

`np.repeat([target], a.ndim, axis=0)` repeats `(0, 1, 0)` for `a.ndim` times and it gives

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Then, we want to change part of each row to `slice(None)`. We cannot do it directly as the type of `slice` object is different from `int`. Thus, we use `astype(object)` to change the type of the array.

Comment: (removed my comment about the original answer to avoid confusion)

Comment: Tested and working, figured out the mechanism too, great answer!

Comment: @OferSadan thank you for your comments and verification. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do can be done programmatically using a `slice` object that is instantiated using the `slice` function — e.g., see [" Dealing with variable numbers of indices within programs"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs).

```
def broadcast_val(mat, val, indices):
    shape = mat.shape
    for i in len(indices):
        len_axis = shape[i]
        i_axis = slice(len_axis)
        index_tuple = *indices[:i], i_axis, *indices[i+1:]
        mat[index_tuple] = val
```

I wonder if it is possible to do what you want using a single assignment...

Comment: I also wonder that... I chose the other answer for readability but thanks for the help, that link really set me on the right path

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to generate string of exactly the 3 lines of code you're currently using, and then execute them:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones([3,3,3])
coord = [1, 1, 1]

for i in range(len(coord)):
   temp = coord[:]
   temp[i] = ':'
   slice_str = ','.join(map(str, temp))
   exec("a[%s] = 0"%slice_str)

print a
```

This may not be the best approach, but at least it's amusing. Now that we know that it works, we can go out and find the appropriate syntax to do it without actually generating the string and `exec`ing it. For example, you could use `slice`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones([3,3,3])
coord = [1, 1, 1]

for i, length in enumerate(a.shape):
   temp = coord[:]
   temp[i] = slice(length)
   a[temp] = 0
print a
```